# What are the qualities of this coil?

Tags: transformer

[image: Phytron coil]
This coil was donated to me. If someone could define it's specifications I would be most grateful. Also feel free to input suggestions for alternative uses.

Comment: From the label: 230 Vac input, 50 / 60 Hz, 664 VA. The physical size of the transformer is consistent with the VA rating.

Comment: Where did you get it? We normally advise "No datasheet, no sale!"

Comment: Your next step is to identify which wires show continuity with each other. Measure the DC resistance of each winding. Add all that information to your original question.

Comment: Transformers are often custom-wound.  If it was designed for a specific piece of equipment, you'll need to reverse-engineer the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not, much universal practical use.

The secondary windings appear to be matched to a somewhat older standard for stepper drivers at 140Vdc with 172Vdc boost using an appropriate synchrotron SMPS controller and connected to a stepper motor with a brake winding.

It’s not clear how this transformer would fit in, but if you want a step down transformer for some other purpose.  the windings have a center tap with 3 wire for those secondaries.

https://www.chicagopartsnetwork.com/By-County-/DuPage-County-/Fans-and-Blower-/Msd-mini-172-140-powerpack.ASPX

the copper might be worth a few €?

other than that maybe an audio power amp supply from +70/-70V after adding the SMPS part from who knows where.